# Move to Glassfish-2.x clustered causes connections to timeout after 1hr

Tags: glassfish, corba, iiop, initial-context

We recently moved from Glassfish-2.x not clustered to a Glassfish-2.x clustered environment. Part of the move included using RMI over IIOP instead of connecting to a static server. Everything works great except when our client application sits idle for over an hour the connection to the server is terminated by the server preventing us from doing any lookups. We would like to know how to keep the connection alive for several hours. The OS is set to keep connections open for 2 hours (/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time). Is there a timeout limit that is set in glassfish for connections over IIOP and if there is how can I change it?

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Can't find SerialContextProvider [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:398)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com...
    at com...
    at com...
    at com...
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicRootPaneUI.java:191)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1639)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2851)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:267)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:216)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2928)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2920)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2814)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6065)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1850)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:712)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:990)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:855)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:676)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4523)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at com...
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionAbort(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2862)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionAbort(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2880)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1788)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1263)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2946)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2965)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:2000)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1713)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:175)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1987)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of why RMI over IIOP connections would timeout after an hour and how I could change that timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall in between your server and client? We had this same error and it turns out the firewall was dropping the connections.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We actually moved over to Glassfish 3.1 and from what I am able to tell the problem has disappeared. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. There is a firewall between two communicating Glassfish servers. How did you fix it, Graeme?